# Understanding the Dagger2 Flow (Sample provided)

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, rx-java, dagger-2

I'm trying to wrap my head around the use of Dagger 2 in my project with Retrofit, RxJava, MVP implementation. However, I'm starting small by reading guides and watching videos and just when I thought I understood how it works, it appears I don't. [Here](https://github.com/grandstaish/hello-mvp-dagger-2) is the sample I'm trying to understand.

Module:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
  private App app;

  public AppModule(App app) {
    this.app = app;
  }

  @Provides @Singleton public SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences() {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app);
  }

  @Provides @Singleton public HelloModel provideHelloModel(SchedulerProvider schedulerProvider,
      HelloDiskCache helloDiskCache, HelloService helloService, Clock clock) {
    return new HelloModel(schedulerProvider, helloDiskCache, helloService, clock);
  }

  @Provides public HelloDiskCache provideHelloDiskCache(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    return new HelloDiskCache(prefs);
  }

  @Provides public HelloService provideHelloService() {
    return new HelloService();
  }

  @Provides public SchedulerProvider provideSchedulerProvider() {
    return SchedulerProvider.DEFAULT;
  }

  @Provides public Clock provideClock() {
    return Clock.REAL;
  }

  @Provides @Nullable public LayoutInflaterFactory provideLayoutInflaterFactory() {
      return null;
  }
```

Component

```
@Component(
    modules = AppModule.class
)
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
  HelloModel getHelloModel();
  HelloDiskCache getHelloDiskCache();
  MainActivity inject(MainActivity activity);
  HelloFragment inject(HelloFragment fragment);
}
```

In the fragment, presenter is injected (where is this coming from?)

```
  @Inject HelloPresenter presenter;
```

And in the presenter, there is a constructor injection

```
  @Inject HelloPresenter(HelloModel helloModel) {
this.model = helloModel;
```

}

So, how come we can inject a presenter in the fragment, and why can we inject in the presenter? The answer does not have to be very elaborate I just feel stupid because I can't trace where it is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Inject`-annotated constructor is an alternative to a `@Provides`-annotated method for a dependency when there's not much configuration to do.

Since `HelloPresenter` has such constructor, Dagger discovers it automatically and is able to inject this dependency or use it to construct and provide other objects in the graph.

A class with an `@Inject`-annotated constructor can itself be annotated with a scope annotation (e.g., `@Singleton`). In this case, only components with the matching scope will be able to see it.

In general, this type of providing dependencies is less verbose, but not always you can use it (e.g., `Activity`, `SharedPreferences`). In such cases you have to go with a `@Module` and a `@Provides` method.

Comment: Hmm I see, after the going through some tutorials I was under the impression that all places where the injection will take place needs to be mentioned in the Component, but this only applies to where you call, for example, App.getAppComponent(getActivity()).inject(this) in the fragment for example.

I think my trouble is understanding why I can use @Inject in classes that are not in the Component, and does not do the inject thing in oncreate.

Comment: @buddhabath There may be some confusion about the usages of `@Inject` annotation on fields and constructors, which are quite different. When you annotate a *field* with `@Inject`, you do need to call `App.getAppComponent(getActivity()).inject(this)` to satisfy this dependency. On the other hand, when you annotate a constructor you tell Dagger that it can use this constructor if it ever needs this class in its graph creation activities. There's no way to not call `...inject(this)` in an `Activity` because you have no access to its constructor and cannot provide its fields as constructor params.

Comment: One more great thing about `@Inject` annotated constructors is that its params are provided automatically from the graph and you normally use them to populate your class fields. In you example, `helloModel` in `HelloPresenter(HelloModel helloModel)` is provided from `provideHelloModel()` within the component, since both of these dependency providers are visible to the component.

Comment: That clears some of it up, but say I added a field in the presenter. (I already did, Im just wondering why it works)
In the module i created a provideOmdbService, which returns a retrofit.create(OmdbService.class), and in the presenter I Inject OmdbService  Does this work because of the Inject MainPresenter constructor?

Comment: Here is a paste of what I added, http://pastebin.com/Mde6wKiX, basically I just call refresh2 in presenter on a buttonclick

Comment: @buddhabath Actually, this was something new for me. Apparently, when you have an `@Inject`-annotated constructor, Dagger also tries to satisfy all `@Inject`-annotated fields in this class. Previously, I erroneously thought that you need to manually call `inject(...)` in any case when you have `@Inject`-annotated fields. Thank you.

Comment: Always fun to learn something ^^ thanks for the answers, I learned alot today and ended up refactoring to providing a DataManager to my Presenter constructor, and the DataManager is built within the module with an AccessToken and an ApiService, works like a charm. I just don't like it when it works and I have no clue why :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this sample where Dagger2 used with MVP Architecture

[Dagger2 Android with MVP](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://github.com/rkandoroidrepo/android-dagger2-example)